# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 when trying to publish react native app with expo CLI

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

I'm creating my first React Native app but, when I try to publish it (running in vscode terminal `npm start` and then clicking on: `Publish or republish project...`) i have this error:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are located outside the United States, try using a VPN to the US and THEN publish your App or run simulator. I know this may sound weird, but for me (I'm outside the United States). If I try to publish or run the app on expo I get either connection refused or connection reset.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

1. `exp start`
2. Cancel  `ctrl c`
3. `expo build:android`

I don't know why but I do the same way with expo-cli and it's working!